# Calendar displays 24 hour clock and I need 12 hour clock

Tags: javascript

I have this e-calendar JavaScript code that is displaying 24hour clock format.  How do you get it to change to 12 hour clock?  Forgive the chopped up code, I had to delete some of it to create the post.
I have posted the code below:

```
(function ($) {

var eCalendar = function (options, object) {
    // Initializing global variables
    var adDay = new Date().getDate();
    var adMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    var adYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var dDay = adDay;
    var dMonth = adMonth;
    var dYear = adYear;
    var instance = object;



    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.eCalendar.defaults, options);


    function print() {
        loadEvents();
        var dWeekDayOfMonthStart = new Date(dYear, dMonth, 1).getDay();
        var dLastDayOfMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
        var dLastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate() - dWeekDayOfMonthStart + 1;

        var cBody = $('<div/>').addClass('c-grid');
        var cEvents = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-grid');
        var cEventsBody = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-body');
        cEvents.append($('<div/>').addClass('c-event-title c-pad-top').html(settings.eventTitle));
        cEvents.append(cEventsBody);
        var cNext = $('<div/>').addClass('c-next c-grid-title c-pad-top');
        var cMonth = $('<div/>').addClass('c-month c-grid-title c-pad-top');
        var cPrevious = $('<div/>').addClass('c-previous c-grid-title c-pad-top');
        cPrevious.html(settings.textArrows.previous);
        cMonth.html(settings.months[dMonth] + ' ' + dYear);
        cNext.html(settings.textArrows.next);

        cPrevious.on('mouseover', mouseOver).on('mouseleave', mouseLeave).on('click', previousMonth);
        cNext.on('mouseover', mouseOver).on('mouseleave', mouseLeave).on('click', nextMonth);

        cBody.append(cPrevious);
        cBody.append(cMonth);
        cBody.append(cNext);
        for (var i = 0; i < settings.weekDays.length; i++) {
            var cWeekDay = $('<div/>').addClass('c-week-day c-pad-top');
            cWeekDay.html(settings.weekDays[i]);
            cBody.append(cWeekDay);
        }
        var day = 1;
        var dayOfNextMonth = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            var cDay = $('<div/>');
            if (i < dWeekDayOfMonthStart) {
                cDay.addClass('c-day-previous-month c-pad-top');
                cDay.html(dLastDayOfPreviousMonth++);
            } else if (day <= dLastDayOfMonth) {
                cDay.addClass('c-day c-pad-top');
                if (day == dDay && adMonth == dMonth && adYear == dYear) {
                    cDay.addClass('c-today');
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < settings.events.length; j++) {
                    var d = settings.events[j].datetime;
                    if (d.getDate() == day && (d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
                        cDay.addClass('c-event').attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
                        cDay.on('mouseover', mouseOverEvent).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEvent);
                    }
                }
                cDay.html(day++);
            } else {
                cDay.addClass('c-day-next-month c-pad-top');
                cDay.html(dayOfNextMonth++);
            }
            cBody.append(cDay);
        }
        var eventList = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-list');
        for (var i = 0; i < settings.events.length; i++) {
            var d = settings.events[i].datetime;
            if ((d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
                var date = lpad(d.getDate(), 2) + '/' + lpad(d.getMonth(), 2) + ' ' + lpad(d.getHours(), 2) + ':' + lpad(d.getMinutes(), 2);
                var item = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-item');
                var title = $('<div/>').addClass('title').html(date + '  ' + settings.events[i].title + '<br />');
                var description = $('<div/>').addClass('description').html(settings.events[i].description + '<br />');
                item.attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
                item.on('mouseover', mouseOverItem).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveItem);
                item.append(title).append(description);
                eventList.append(item);
            }
        }
        $(instance).addClass('calendar');
        cEventsBody.append(eventList);
        $(instance).html(cBody).append(cEvents);
    }

    return print();
}

$.fn.eCalendar = function (oInit) {
    return this.each(function () {
        return eCalendar(oInit, $(this));
    });
};



}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Take some time to understand what the code is doing. The part where it computes the digits is quite simple and I'm sure it's not beyond you. Step through the code with a debugger if that helps.

Comment: I have.  Im not that versed on JS which is why Im here. getHour will give me 24 hour format.  I dont know how to change it to 12 hour.

Comment: You're so close! Next up: [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

getHours returns the range 0-23, so if it's greater than 11, subtract 12.

You could even get fancy and do like

(getHours() + 24) % 12 || 12

Comment: var Hours = new Date().getHours() % 12;
if (Hours == 0) {
    Hours += 12;
}      
      that didnt work :(

Comment: I did this:  lpad(d.getHours() %12, 2)  and it worked.  thanks for helping Eric I appreciate it. :)